# Timing issues Matlab to HDL code conversion

Tags: matlab, vhdl, synthesis

I am using Matlab HDL coder (Matlab ver R2012b) for conversion of a matlab code to VHDL. But there seems to be some problem with the timing issues.
I verified the code generated using the 'Cosimulation' tool provided by Matlab, and it seems to work just fine. I am attaching the report being generated below:

```
=========================================================================
HDL Synthesis Report

Macro Statistics
# Multipliers : 12
11x11-bit multiplier : 2
12x12-bit multiplier : 10
# Adders/Subtractors : 16
13-bit adder : 5
15-bit adder : 7
17-bit adder : 3
23-bit adder : 1
# Comparators : 12
23-bit comparator lessequal : 1
24-bit comparator greatequal : 1
24-bit comparator lessequal : 10

=========================================================================
=========================================================================
Advanced HDL Synthesis Report

Macro Statistics
# MACs
: 1
11x11-to-23-bit MAC : 1
# Multipliers : 11
11x11-bit multiplier : 1
12x12-bit multiplier : 10
# Adders/Subtractors : 15
11-bit adder : 11
12-bit adder : 4
# Comparators : 12
23-bit comparator lessequal : 1
24-bit comparator greatequal : 1
24-bit comparator lessequal INFO:TclTasksC:1850 - process run : Synthesize - XST is                         done.
: 10


Timing Summary:
---------------
Speed Grade: -10

Minimum period: No path found
Minimum input arrival time before clock: No path found
Maximum output required time after clock: No path found
Maximum combinational path delay: 94.592ns
```

Can someone please explain about the timing summary and why it is showing 'no path found'. Also, does this imply that the code might not get ported on the FPGA?

P.S. : I am new to using this tool and also don't have much knowledge about VHDL. So, if anyone can explain why this is happening and in a simple manner, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Apparently you have created an unclocked design, which is why timing analysis only reports combinational paths. You'll need to learn how to create clocked (and pipelined, to improve that awful speed) designs via HDL Coder. (I confess I gave up on HDL Coder, finding it easier to simply write VHDL)

Comment: I tend to trust Brian on these things.  For the rest of us you can google *MATLAB HDL Coder filetype:pdf* and the first half dozen or so Mathworks PDF files that come up with tells the story of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have gone through the internet resources on HDL coder, but most of them discuss on how to use the tool. I have become familiar with the tool, although I still don't know how to code so that it gets translated to a clocked design. If anyone can please guide me through this, it will be a great help.